# SQL Group by and Aggregate

Tags: sql

I have a table in this structure:

```
editor_id
rev_user
rev_year
rev_month
rev_page
edit_count
```

here is the sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cbb1/1

I need to provide list of rev_pages edited by the most active editor, along with the number of editing acts he has invested at each document.
i.e. I need to find the most active editor (sum 'edit_count' of rev_page of each year and month) and then find all the pages he edited.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Is the target database MySQL? I'm just making sure because there are easier ways to do this with less subqueries if you use analytical functions, I think, which are not available in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your problem completely but still i tried. I hope this will be helpful to you.

```
SELECT REV_USER, REV_YEAR, REV_MONTH, SUM(EDIT_COUNT) 
FROM edit_count_user_date 
GROUP BY REV_USER, REV_YEAR, REV_MONTH 
ORDER BY REV_YEAR
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cbb1/25